# Django: "django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes.ds" crashes with "attributeerror: symbol not found"

Tags: django, gis, geodjango

Running the latest Django *(3.0.4)* I am now getting this:

```
  File "[...]site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
  File "[...]site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/prototypes/ds.py", line 71, in <module>
    get_field_as_integer64 = int64_output(lgdal.OGR_F_GetFieldAsInteger64, [c_void_p, c_int])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 361, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 366, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: dlsym(0x101667060, OGR_F_GetFieldAsInteger64): symbol not found
```

**My Observations:**

I have [ellided] the path names which refer to Django in my virtual-environment.  I observe that the module that is actually crashing is in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/ ...` this on Macintosh OS/X Catalina.

The version of Python that is installed on this computer is 3.6.4.  (The version on the hosting service is considerably older ... 3.4.)

Is this, as I suspect, a problem with the Python *installation* on this computer?  (The most recent version that can be installed here is 3.7.7.)

---

**EDIT:** ***NO, it isn't!***

After installing Django 3.0.4 on a Linux host I got this:

```
 AttributeError: /usr/local/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: OGR_F_GetFieldAsInteger64
```

Now, once again this is a system-wide library that's being called, but I now suspect that the root cause problem is actually in this line:

```
   File "[...]/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/prototypes/ds.py", line 71, in <module>
get_field_as_integer64 = int64_output(lgdal.OGR_F_GetFieldAsInteger64, [c_void_p, c_int])
```

I am now rolling Django versions backward to see if I can make the problem go away and if so "answer my own question."

Comment: I've got same problem here. No solutions yet?

Answer (score 0):

I had to walk back ***all the way to Django 2.1*** before the problem finally went away.

libgdal version 1.6 is installed on this computer's virtual-environment and I don't know if it is practical nor possible for me to change it.  ("gcc" is installed here, "configure" is not.)